# Swift: Compare the first character of string

Tags: swift, string, nsstring

How can I compare the first character of a String against a character in Swift? For example:

Pseudo code:

```
str = "my name is John"

if str[0] == m {
}
```

Comment: It's spelt "pseudo code"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
let s = "abcd"

if s.hasPrefix("a") {  // takes a String or a literal
}

if s.first == "a" {  // takes a Character or a literal
}

if s[s.startIndex] == "a" { // takes a Character or a literal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for any charactor comparision in **Swift 3**:

```
    var str: String = "abcd"    

    if str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)] == "a" {

    }
```

where, 
i = use any index value of string
In above example it is 0
i = 0